# Xamarin App cannot syncronize with SQL Server DB with an identity column

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-asynctask, synchronization, identity-column

I have a SQL Server DB with an identity int column (IdProspecto) that increments automatically and is used as Primary key to link with other tables in the DB.
Now I'm creating an Xamarin App using Azure Easy tables. I've problems to synchronise with this column:

> "Cannot update identity column 'IdProspecto'".

The possible solutions I'm considering are:
1. Change IdProspecto from autonumeric int to a Guid, and use this field as the Id that the easy Table requires. (it requires a lot of changes in my DB)
2. Avoid that the update include set IdProspecto when I use:

```
await this.prospectosTable.PullAsync("allProspectos", this.prospectosTable.CreateQuery());
```

Is it possible? (But I need to GET this value to be used to link the new records of the related tables.)
What is the easiest solution?

This is the model:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MobileAppVaniplas
{

    public class Prospectos 
    {
        string id;
        string empresa;
        string tipoCliente;
        string gerente;
        string contacto;
        string cargoContacto;
        string ciudad;

        string telefono1;
        string telefono2;
        string celular;
        string direccion;
        string email;
        string paginaweb;
        string calendarioColegio;
        string observaciones;
        string estado;
        string prioridad;
        DateTime fechaCreacion;
        string creadoPor;


        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "idProspecto")] 
        public string IdProspecto  //Mayusculas segun BD
        {
            get { return idProspecto; }
            set { idProspecto = value; }
        }


        [Version]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tipoCliente")]
        public string TipoCliente
        {
            get { return tipoCliente; }
            set { tipoCliente = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "empresa")]
        public string Empresa
        {
            get { return empresa; }
            set { empresa = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "gerente")]
        public string Gerente
        {
            get { return gerente; }
            set { gerente = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contacto")]
        public string Contacto
        {
            get { return contacto; }
            set { contacto = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cargoContacto")]
        public string CargoContacto
        {
            get { return cargoContacto; }
            set { cargoContacto = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ciudad")]
        public string Ciudad
        {
            get { return ciudad; }
            set { ciudad = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "telefono1")]
        public string Telefono1
        {
            get { return telefono1; }
            set { telefono1 = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "telefono2")]
        public string Telefono2
        {
            get { return telefono2; }
            set { telefono2 = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "celular")]
        public string Celular
        {
            get { return celular; }
            set { celular = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "direccion")]
        public string Direccion
        {
            get { return direccion; }
            set { direccion = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
        public string eMail
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "paginaweb")]
        public string paginaWEB
        {
            get { return paginaweb; }
            set { paginaweb = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "calendarioColegio")]
        public string CalendarioColegio
        {
            get { return calendarioColegio; }
            set { calendarioColegio = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "observaciones")]
        public string Observaciones
        {
            get { return observaciones; }
            set { observaciones = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "estado")]
        public string Estado
        {
            get { return estado; }
            set { estado = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "prioridad")]
        public string Prioridad
        {
            get { return prioridad; }
            set { prioridad = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fechaCreacion")]
        public DateTime FechaCreacion
        {
            get { return fechaCreacion; }
            set { fechaCreacion = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "creadoPor")]
        public string CreadoPor
        {
            get { return creadoPor; }
            set { creadoPor = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the function I use to syncronize:

```
 public async Task SyncAsync() 
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;

        try
        {

            await this.client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            await this.prospectosTable.PullAsync("allProspectos", this.prospectosTable.CreateQuery());
        }
        catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
        {
            if (exc.PushResult != null)
            {
                syncErrors = exc.PushResult.Errors;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show some code here? Because I am not sure about your problem.

Comment: Cherry, I added some code as you asked me.